# GeoJSON to masks

Tags: python, geojson, rasterio, masking, extract-by-mask

I need to use the GeoJSON file and TIFF images to produce masks. Is there a Python program that takes GeoJSON file and TIFF image as input and produces masks?

Comment: Also see https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`rasterio.mask` method](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/masking-by-shapefile.html):

```
import fiona
import rasterio
import rasterio.mask

with fiona.open("file.geojson", "r") as geojson:
   features = [feature["geometry"] for feature in geojson]

with rasterio.open("file.tiff") as src:
   out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, features, crop=True)
   out_meta = src.meta
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It runs, but I cannot see the output. How can I display the mask and save it as a tiff image? Appreciate your help!

Comment: You can [write](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/writing.html) instead of just read the file and plot it [using matplotlib](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/plotting.html). If you think my answer has solved your question, please mark it as solved to help other users.